# Identifying similar string values in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

For example, I have the following table with two columns, `Address1` and `refAddr`.

Some sample data in the tables looks like this.

[image]

I would like to compare the two columns for match. And apparently in this table, `5235 JFK BLVD` & `5235 John F Kennedy` are a pair, and `424 N 2ND ST` & `424 NORTH SECOND` are a pair.

Is there anyway in SQL or in SSIS I can use to get rid of non-pair results and retain the pairs?

Comment: Address matching and fixing is special purpose software that is not normally included in a database.

Comment: Buy a master data management software to do this.

Comment: Use a script component with regex in SSIS and mark those rows that match in an additional column, then you can just filter these rows.

Comment: regex bad in this case... there are a lot of string similarity functions out there and they are all geared for different things this particular issue of addresses you then need a lot more logic as well such as alias tables.  The trick is you have to have standardized and parsed address and then compare.  but one much easier way (and typically cheaper than @dfundako's MDM suggestion) would be to geocode them and then compare the geopoint.  Depending on your size of your dataset you can do this at a relatively lower cost.

Comment: oh and I agree with Gordon that it is not usually in the database, but I like it there due to a particular need in our transnational systems and am writing some CLRs for the purpose

Comment: @Matt yeah i do understand that...but this practice is usually just once a month in my company and usually it is just about 50 entries. Purchasing a separate software isn't really what the business looks for...

Comment: only 50 entries then I definitely say use a batch geocoding process and then just compare their gps position.  there are a bunch out there that you can upload a csv/excel to and get your results for free then just re-import and be done.... or write something against the google api.  This will be far simpler than trying to learn address parsing and string matching!

Comment: I don't know if they would even sell to you at that level but Melissa Data has address matching and verification ssis components that are easy to implement in ssis.  But that is like bringing the 10,000 pound gorilla to the table but wouldn't be more than a couple hundred dollars a year....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is you can use the GOOGLE API to geocode the address, parse the JSON results to return a more standardized results.  This could be time consuming, but you will have more confidence in the data.

The API allows for (I believe) 2,500 hits per day, but you can purchase more.

For example, I picked 5232 JFK Blvd and added a zip code of 72116 to narrow down the search.  Without the zip code it returned multiple addresses (NY, NJ, AR, etc)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=5232%20JFK%20Blvd&72116sensor=false
```

The key elements may be:

```
formatted_address: "5232 J.F.K. Blvd, North Little Rock, AR 72116, USA",
or
long_name: "John F. Kennedy Boulevard",
```

Returns

```
{
results: [
{
address_components: [
{
long_name: "5232",
short_name: "5232",
types: [
"street_number"
]
},
{
long_name: "J.F.K. Boulevard",
short_name: "J.F.K. Blvd",
types: [
"route"
]
},
{
long_name: "North Little Rock",
short_name: "North Little Rock",
types: [
"locality",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "Hill Township",
short_name: "Hill Township",
types: [
"administrative_area_level_3",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "Pulaski County",
short_name: "Pulaski County",
types: [
"administrative_area_level_2",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "Arkansas",
short_name: "AR",
types: [
"administrative_area_level_1",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "United States",
short_name: "US",
types: [
"country",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "72116",
short_name: "72116",
types: [
"postal_code"
]
}
],
formatted_address: "5232 J.F.K. Blvd, North Little Rock, AR 72116, USA",
geometry: {
bounds: {
northeast: {
lat: 34.8032656,
lng: -92.2538364
},
southwest: {
lat: 34.8032599,
lng: -92.2538538
}
},
location: {
lat: 34.8032599,
lng: -92.2538364
},
location_type: "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 34.8046117302915,
lng: -92.2524961197085
},
southwest: {
lat: 34.8019137697085,
lng: -92.2551940802915
}
}
},
place_id: "EjI1MjMyIEouRi5LLiBCbHZkLCBOb3J0aCBMaXR0bGUgUm9jaywgQVIgNzIxMTYsIFVTQQ",
types: [
"route",
"street_address"
]
},
{
address_components: [
{
long_name: "5232",
short_name: "5232",
types: [
"street_number"
]
},
{
long_name: "John F. Kennedy Boulevard",
short_name: "John F. Kennedy Blvd",
types: [
"route"
]
},
{
long_name: "West New York",
short_name: "West New York",
types: [
"locality",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "Hudson County",
short_name: "Hudson County",
types: [
"administrative_area_level_2",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "New Jersey",
short_name: "NJ",
types: [
"administrative_area_level_1",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "United States",
short_name: "US",
types: [
"country",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "07093",
short_name: "07093",
types: [
"postal_code"
]
}
],
formatted_address: "5232 John F. Kennedy Blvd, West New York, NJ 07093, USA",
geometry: {
bounds: {
northeast: {
lat: 40.78574,
lng: -74.0231416
},
southwest: {
lat: 40.7857366,
lng: -74.0231598
}
},
location: {
lat: 40.78574,
lng: -74.0231416
},
location_type: "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 40.78708728029149,
lng: -74.02180171970849
},
southwest: {
lat: 40.7843893197085,
lng: -74.0244996802915
}
}
},
place_id: "Ejc1MjMyIEpvaG4gRi4gS2VubmVkeSBCbHZkLCBXZXN0IE5ldyBZb3JrLCBOSiAwNzA5MywgVVNB",
types: [
"route",
"street_address"
]
}
],
status: "OK"
}
```